# In The Time Machine, why does Wells leave the protagonist unnamed?

Tags: names, h.g.wells, the-time-machine

H. G. Wells leaves the main character of his novel *The Time Machine* without a name. The two times that he would have given a name, it was replaced with underlines. Why would he do this?

Comment: Tricks like this were often done to give the impression that it was a true story, and that the names of the people concerned were redacted away (rather than being replaced with made up names like we do today in true stories).

Comment: @MrLister Ray Cummings, perhaps imitating Wells, did something like that in writing [*The Girl in the Golden Atom*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21094): the protagonist is the Chemist, and he recounts his adventures to his friends the Doctor, the Very Young Man, the Banker, and the Big Business Man.

Comment: Perhaps because in a sense it was the absolute most important aspect of him, that he was a time traveler, more important than some name or regular title. This was a title of such singular distinction that class conscious Victorian England could do no less than refer to him solely by his title.

Comment: Note that the officially authorized sequel [Time Ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Ships) by Stephen Baxter _does_ give a name for character towards the end (I won't spoil it here, though), and even a reason as to why he (the character) avoided its mentioning

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments, this is common practice in fiction from that time.

This is not the only work of H.G.Wells to use the practice, for example *The Man Who Could Work Miracles*.

Many works of Edgar Allen Poe use the same trick.  Particularly for characters peripheral to the story.  Examples include *The Murders in the Rue Morgue* and *The Unparalleled Adventure of One Hans Pfaall*.

H.Rider Haggard uses the trick in *She* when referring to characters other than those actually on the journey to find Ayesha.

The practice is especially common in short stories and of works initially published in a magazine.  Again, as @Mr.Lister put in his comment, this gave the impression of protecting the identity of people.  Magazines often did this in real stories to avoid any risk of libel suits.

Comment: I've seen the same thing done with dates in works of the time.